# Rails join table query. How can i use the attribute of a nested child to order a parent

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I'm a little stuck with a query.

I have a table called Videos

`Videos has_many posts (one video can be post in ig and/or fb)`

`Post has_one metric`

`Metric has a json with data['views']`

**I need to order my videos by data views. The video with more views, needs to be on top**

*This query returns all the videos with the diferent posts and metrics*

```
@published_videos = current_account&.videos&.joins(:posts)&.includes(posts: %i[last_two_days_metrics metric]).distinct
```

This method sums the views of the posts of a video.

```
def sum_of_posts_views
  self.posts.map do |post|
    post.metric&.data&.dig("views")
  end.sum
end
```

What I'm looking is how can I order the videos by the data['views'] attribute, or how can I order them by the method sum_of_posts_views

Comment: You would typically handle this by joining the other table and and using an aggregate function in the ORDER clause such as: `Foo.group(:id).left_joins(:bars).order("SUM(bars.baz)")`. Doing it in Ruby would require you to pull everything out of the database and won't work if you have a non-trivial amount of data.

Comment: For JSON you want something like `order('SUM(metrics.data#>{views})')`. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-json.html